# What are the ways from which I can remove scratches from my bike tank

Tags: honda, motorcycle

I have a bike honda shine 125cc. It looks good, but when any scratches made I feel very sad, I want to remove all these scratches from bike tank, so it again looks good, What are the ways from which I can remove these scratches. How can I achive this without expending much cost?

Comment: Pics or it never happened

Comment: plz wait....I will update the pics soon.

Comment: Pics.  I can't see what you are talking about.

Answer (score 2):

It very much depends on the depth and severity of the scratches, a photograph would help here.

For minor scratches polishing and waxing the paintwork may yield the results you are after.  If the scratches are deeper, polishing with an abrasive such as cutting paste or a product such as T-cut prior to applying wax may do the trick.

If the damage to the paintwork is too deep and severe, the simplest way to repair it is to repaint the part.  This doesn't need to be a particularly expensive operation, especially if you can remove the tank from the bike yourself.

Once you are happy with the paintwork, regular applications of wax / "sealant" finishing polish ought to guard against further scratches.